# unable to label a line in \align* environment with tag being a matrix

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I try to do this

```
\begin{align*}
\label{labelname}\tag{$\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\end{smallmatrix}$}a=b\\
c=d
\end{align*}
```

But it does not allow me to add the label and pops up an error message saying

> Use of \math@cr@@ doesn't match its definition.
>   \new@ifnextchar ...ved@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2}
>                                                    \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...

If I use a more normal tag, such as

```
\tag{$e_2(x)$}
```

Then the label works.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Might also be nice to know why you can to add a matrix as a tag? That is not particularly standard and thus may confuse readers.

Answer (score 4):

You should `\protect` the fragile macros: `\begin`, `\\` and `\end`, so

```
\tag{$\protect\begin{smallmatrix}0\protect\\1\protect\end{smallmatrix}$}
```

However, you can avoid this cumbersome approach with a cleaner macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mathtag}[1]{%
  \tag{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{$#1$}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\label{labelname}\mathtag{\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\end{smallmatrix}}a=b\\
c=d
\end{align*}
And \eqref{labelname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I save the tag in a box in advance, and then use it inside the tag.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox\tagA
\newsavebox\tagB
\begin{document}
\savebox\tagA{$\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\end{smallmatrix}$}
\begin{align*}
\label{labelA}\tag{\usebox{\tagA}}a=b\\
c=d
\end{align*}

\savebox\tagB{$\begin{smallmatrix}2\\3\end{smallmatrix}$}
\begin{align*}
\label{labelB}\tag{\usebox{\tagB}}e=f\\
g=h
\end{align*}

Comparing \ref{labelA} and \ref{labelB}...
\end{document}
```

[image]